# No response from remote client: error during file transfer using asmack

Tags: android, xmpp, smack, asmack

I have a problem while receiving file using asmack. Here I paste error and packets that I sent and receive log

```
// error
04-21 19:21:05.109: WARN/System.err(7401): Error in execution:
04-21 19:21:05.109: WARN/System.err(7401):   -- caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
04-21 19:21:05.109: WARN/System.err(7401):   -- caused by: No response from remote client:
04-21 19:21:05.109: WARN/System.err(7401):     at org.jivesoftware.smackx.filetransfer.IncomingFileTransfer.negotiateStream(IncomingFileTransfer.java:199)
04-21 19:21:05.109: WARN/System.err(7401):     at org.jivesoftware.smackx.filetransfer.IncomingFileTransfer.access$100(IncomingFileTransfer.java:47)
04-21 19:21:05.109: WARN/System.err(7401):     at org.jivesoftware.smackx.filetransfer.IncomingFileTransfer$1.run(IncomingFileTransfer.java:124)
04-21 19:21:05.109: WARN/System.err(7401):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
04-21 19:21:05.109: WARN/System.err(7401): Nested Exception:
04-21 19:21:05.109: WARN/System.err(7401): java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
04-21 19:21:05.109: WARN/System.err(7401):   -- caused by: No response from remote client:
04-21 19:21:05.109: WARN/System.err(7401):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerGet(FutureTask.java:234)
04-21 19:21:05.109: WARN/System.err(7401):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:91)
04-21 19:21:05.109: WARN/System.err(7401):     at org.jivesoftware.smackx.filetransfer.IncomingFileTransfer.negotiateStream(IncomingFileTransfer.java:193)
04-21 19:21:05.109: WARN/System.err(7401):     at org.jivesoftware.smackx.filetransfer.IncomingFileTransfer.access$100(IncomingFileTransfer.java:47)
04-21 19:21:05.109: WARN/System.err(7401):     at org.jivesoftware.smackx.filetransfer.IncomingFileTransfer$1.run(IncomingFileTransfer.java:124)
04-21 19:21:05.109: WARN/System.err(7401):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
04-21 19:21:05.109: WARN/System.err(7401): Caused by:
04-21 19:21:05.109: WARN/System.err(7401):   -- caused by: No response from remote client:
04-21 19:21:05.167: WARN/System.err(7401):     at org.jivesoftware.smackx.filetransfer.FaultTolerantNegotiator.createIncomingStream(FaultTolerantNegotiator.java:113)
04-21 19:21:05.167: WARN/System.err(7401):     at org.jivesoftware.smackx.filetransfer.IncomingFileTransfer$2.call(IncomingFileTransfer.java:186)
04-21 19:21:05.217: WARN/System.err(7401):     at org.jivesoftware.smackx.filetransfer.IncomingFileTransfer$2.call(IncomingFileTransfer.java:183)
04-21 19:21:05.217: WARN/System.err(7401):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
04-21 19:21:05.217: WARN/System.err(7401):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
04-21 19:21:05.236: WARN/System.err(7401):     at org.jivesoftware.smackx.filetransfer.IncomingFileTransfer.negotiateStream(IncomingFileTransfer.java:190)
04-21 19:21:05.236: WARN/System.err(7401):     ... 3 more




// packets sent and received:
04-21 19:20:53.177: INFO/System.out(7401): 07:20:53 PM RCV  (1079262448): <presence from='nirav@mychathost/Smack' to='rtest@mychathost/Smack' id='fDXhN-22'><c xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/caps' hash='sha-1' node='http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/smack/' ver='zAGnwwThW7wuhrojiPg9I4Spwms='/></presence>
04-21 19:20:54.479: INFO/System.out(7401): 07:20:54 PM RCV  (1079262448): <presence from='nirav@mychathost/Smack' to='rtest@mychathost/Smack' id='fDXhN-23'><c xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/caps' hash='sha-1' node='http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/smack/' ver='zAGnwwThW7wuhrojiPg9I4Spwms='/></presence>
04-21 19:20:54.602: INFO/System.out(7401): 07:20:54 PM RCV  (1079262448): <iq from='nirav@mychathost/Smack' to='rtest@mychathost/Smack' id='fDXhN-24' type='set'><si xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/si' id='jsi_5262843704368872277' profile='http://jabber.org/protocol/si/profile/file-transfer'><file xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/si/profile/file-transfer' name='rails.png' size='6646'><desc>rails.png</desc></file><feature xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/feature-neg'><x xmlns='jabber:x:data' type='form'><field var='stream-method' type='list-multi'><option><value>http://jabber.org/protocol/bytestreams</value></option><option><value>http://jabber.org/protocol/ibb</value></option></field></x></feature></si></iq>
04-21 19:20:54.639: DEBUG/Lisner Called(7401): Incoming Listner
04-21 19:20:54.658: DEBUG/file name(7401): rails.png
04-21 19:20:54.658: DEBUG/file status(7401): Initial
04-21 19:20:54.658: DEBUG/file size(7401): 6646
04-21 19:20:54.684: DEBUG/file path(7401): /mnt/sdcard/DCIM/Camera/rails.png
04-21 19:20:54.684: DEBUG/Receive(7401): before receive
04-21 19:20:54.712: DEBUG/R1(7401): after receive
04-21 19:20:54.772: INFO/System.out(7401): 07:20:54 PM SENT (1079262448): <iq id="fDXhN-24" to="nirav@mychathost/Smack" from="rtest@mychathost/Smack" type="result"><si xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/si"><feature xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/feature-neg"><x xmlns="jabber:x:data" type="submit"><field var="stream-method"><value>http://jabber.org/protocol/bytestreams</value><value>http://jabber.org/protocol/ibb</value></field></x></feature></si></iq>
04-21 19:20:55.724: INFO/transfere file(7401): receiving file status Negotiating Stream progress: 0.0
04-21 19:20:56.765: INFO/transfere file(7401): receiving file status Negotiating Stream progress: 0.0
04-21 19:20:57.810: INFO/transfere file(7401): receiving file status Negotiating Stream progress: 0.0
04-21 19:20:58.330: INFO/System.out(7401): 07:20:58 PM RCV  (1079262448): <iq from='nirav@mychathost/Smack' to='rtest@mychathost/Smack' id='fDXhN-26' type='set'><query xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/bytestreams' sid='jsi_5262843704368872277' mode='tcp'><streamhost jid='nirav@mychathost/Smack' host='127.0.0.1' port='7777'/></query></iq>
04-21 19:20:58.425: INFO/System.out(7401): 07:20:58 PM SENT (1079262448): <iq id="fDXhN-26" to="nirav@mychathost/Smack" from="rtest@mychathost/Smack" type="error"><query xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/bytestreams" sid="jsi_5262843704368872277" mode = "tcp"><streamhost jid="nirav@mychathost/Smack" host="127.0.0.1" port="7777"/></query><error code="404" type="CANCEL"><item-not-found xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas"/><text xml:lang="en" xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas">Could not establish socket with any provided host</text></error></iq>
04-21 19:20:58.874: INFO/transfere file(7401): receiving file status Negotiating Stream progress: 0.0
04-21 19:20:59.943: INFO/transfere file(7401): receiving file status Negotiating Stream progress: 0.0
04-21 19:21:00.765: INFO/System.out(7401): 07:21:00 PM RCV  (1079262448): <iq from='nirav@mychathost/Smack' to='rtest@mychathost/Smack' id='fDXhN-27' type='set'><open xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/ibb' block-size='4096' sid='jsi_5262843704368872277' stanza='iq'/></iq>
04-21 19:21:00.804: INFO/System.out(7401): 07:21:00 PM SENT (1079262448): <iq id="fDXhN-27" to="nirav@mychathost/Smack" from="rtest@mychathost/Smack" type="error"><error code="501" type="CANCEL"><feature-not-implemented xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas"/></error></iq>
04-21 19:21:00.978: INFO/transfere file(7401): receiving file status Negotiating Stream progress: 0.0
04-21 19:21:02.017: INFO/transfere file(7401): receiving file status Negotiating Stream progress: 0.0
04-21 19:21:03.039: INFO/transfere file(7401): receiving file status Negotiating Stream progress: 0.0
04-21 19:21:04.071: INFO/transfere file(7401): receiving file status Negotiating Stream progress: 0.0
04-21 19:21:05.109: INFO/transfere file(7401): receiving file status Error progress: 0.0
```

Comment: if you got solution than you can help me, my chat app with ejabberd server and between android clients working properly but when i send any file than the progress of sending stuck at 0.0..what could be the reason?

Answer (score 4):

Dude Just copy and paste following code,

```
private void receiveFile(XMPPConnection connection2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(connection2 != null){
        ServiceDiscoveryManager sdm =      ServiceDiscoveryManager.getInstanceFor(connection2);
        if (sdm == null){
            sdm = new ServiceDiscoveryManager(connection2);
        }
        sdm.addFeature("http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#info");
        sdm.addFeature("jabber:iq:privacy");
        FileTransferManager manager = new FileTransferManager(connection2);

        manager.addFileTransferListener(new FileTransferListener() {

            public void fileTransferRequest(final FileTransferRequest request) {
                new Thread(){

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        IncomingFileTransfer transfer = request.accept();                           
                        File mf = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();                
                        final File file = new File(mf.getAbsoluteFile() +"/"+ transfer.getFileName());
                        try{
                            transfer.recieveFile(file);
                            while(!transfer.isDone()){
                               try{
                                  Thread.sleep(1000);
                               }
                               catch (Exception e) {
                                  Log.e("", e.getMessage());
                               }
                               if(transfer.getStatus().equals(Status.error)) {
                                  Log.e("ERROR!!! ", transfer.getError() + "");
                               }
                               if(transfer.getException() != null) {
                                  transfer.getException().printStackTrace();
                               }
                            }
                            handler.post(new Runnable() {

                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                    String xMsg = textViewSent.getText().toString();
                                    String newMessage = "File Received at "+file.getAbsolutePath();
                                    textViewSent.setText("\n"+xMsg+"\n"+newMessage);
                                }
                            });
                         }
                        catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }                           
                     };
                   }.start();
            }
        });
    }
```

Please remember to vote...

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing your code its hard to assess the problem. However, I originally had the same problem as you because I was using `InputStream stream = transfer.recieveFile();`. This was fixed by using `transfer.recieveFile(new File(getExternalFilesDir(null), transfer.getFileName()));`. Try adding the listener like this ...

```
fileTransferManager.addFileTransferListener(new FileTransferListener() {
    @Override
    public void fileTransferRequest(FileTransferRequest request) {
        try {
             IncomingFileTransfer transfer = request.accept();
             transfer.recieveFile(new File(getExternalFilesDir(null), transfer.getFileName()));
             String line;
             BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(getExternalFilesDir(null), transfer.getFileName())));
             while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                 System.out.println(line);
             }
        } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

From your logs:

```
04-21 19:20:58.330: INFO/System.out(7401): 07:20:58 PM RCV  (1079262448): <iq from='nirav@mychathost/Smack' to='rtest@mychathost/Smack' id='fDXhN-26' type='set'><query xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/bytestreams' sid='jsi_5262843704368872277' mode='tcp'><streamhost jid='nirav@mychathost/Smack' host='127.0.0.1' port='7777'/></query></iq>
04-21 19:20:58.425: INFO/System.out(7401): 07:20:58 PM SENT (1079262448): <iq id="fDXhN-26" to="nirav@mychathost/Smack" from="rtest@mychathost/Smack" type="error"><query xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/bytestreams" sid="jsi_5262843704368872277" mode = "tcp"><streamhost jid="nirav@mychathost/Smack" host="127.0.0.1" port="7777"/></query><error code="404" type="CANCEL"><item-not-found xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas"/><text xml:lang="en" xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas">Could not establish socket with any provided host</text></error></iq>
....
04-21 19:21:00.765: INFO/System.out(7401): 07:21:00 PM RCV  (1079262448): <iq from='nirav@mychathost/Smack' to='rtest@mychathost/Smack' id='fDXhN-27' type='set'><open xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/ibb' block-size='4096' sid='jsi_5262843704368872277' stanza='iq'/></iq>
04-21 19:21:00.804: INFO/System.out(7401): 07:21:00 PM SENT (1079262448): <iq id="fDXhN-27" to="nirav@mychathost/Smack" from="rtest@mychathost/Smack" type="error"><error code="501" type="CANCEL"><feature-not-implemented xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas"/></error></iq>
```

The [bytestream transfer method](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0065.html) failes, because there is only a local (127.0.0.1) streamhost configured. The [in-band bytestream](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0047.html) failes because the other party doesn't support IBB.

You should:

- Configure a valid streamhost that acts as proxy ([XEP-65 Section 6 "Mediated Connection"](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0065.html#mediated))
- Enable IBB if possible